# How could I implement a movement system like Intrusion 2 has?

Tags: physics, animation, skeletal-animation

Here is [a trailer of the game Intrusion 2](https://youtu.be/BJZAzNKZBew). The characters seem to move with physics, but look animated as well.

I'd like to know how such a movement system works and how I could go about implementing something similar.

Comment: (It looks like [2d skeletal animation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=2d+skeletal+parts) of a sort, which there have been a few questions about on the site that might help.)